# Angular always fails to load on launching application and Ctrl+F5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, page-refresh

I am working on Asp.net MVC 5 Application with Angular 2.

Whenever I try to launch the application Angular 2 fails to initialize, but it works on refreshing the browser.

Same applies for Ctrl+F5 as well, it's failing to load angular.

Any help, also may I know the reason for why it's not working on the startup?

[image]

**App.component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';    

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
  <div class="page-container">
            <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
            <tree-bar></tree-bar>
            @*@Html.Partial("_SidebarPartial")*@
            @*@Html.Partial("_SidebarTrial")*@
            <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <!-- BEGIN CONTENT BODY -->
                <div class="page-content">
                    <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEADER-->
                    <!-- BEGIN PAGE BAR -->
                    @RenderSection("pageBar", false)
                    <!-- END PAGE BAR -->
                    <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h1 class="page-title">
                                @ViewBag.PageTitle
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.PageSubTitle))
                                {
                                    <br />
                                    <small>@ViewBag.PageSubTitle</small>
                                }
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h1 class="page-title pull-right" ">
                                @RenderSection("PageOptions", false)
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END PAGE TITLE-->
                    <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->

                    @RenderBody()
                    <my-app></my-app>
                </div>
                <!-- END CONTENT BODY -->
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT -->
            <!-- BEGIN QUICK SIDEBAR -->

            <tenantswitching></tenantswitching>


            <!-- END QUICK SIDEBAR -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Appcomponent code will help a bit can you post

Comment: Please post the component and template code please ...

Comment: Sure, post edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to load the Angular dependencies and scripts on Head Tag.
This was the reason for the failure.

Now, I am load loading the same below the body tag. Now it works fine!